# Trouble with using Biblatex with self-made package for my thesis

Tags: biblatex, memoir, package-writing

I have been working on a package in which to place all layout codes for my thesis. Here I also define the Biblatex codes. I am, however, having some trouble with getting biblatex to function properly.

I edit in TexStudio, and this editing software usually suggest codes as I start typing them. Specifically for citations, I get a box of all possible citations matching my entries as I type. I am sure many of you are familiar with this. TexStudio does that when I use "article" class with biblatex, but not with memoir and my own "package".

I was hoping someone experienced could take a quick look and see if they find something that may cause the problem. I use biber as the backend, and I have set TexStudio for this option, and specified in loading biblatex. The package file is not very large (about 100 lines).

I have made a MWE, and I also post here the entire content of my package. That way you can just copy the lines, past them into a new document and save as a .sty file, and you should be good to go - I cannot upload files here. I also post the content of my .bib file, for you to copy-past.

I appreciate any help on the issue!

**.tex file:**

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{assignments}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello World}
Here I make a preposterous claim, which is supported by \textcite{kelleher2000idpt}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**.bib file**

```
@article{kelleher2000idpt,
    Author = {P. Kelleher AND K. Pacheco AND L. S. Newman},
    Date = {2000},
    Date-Added = {2014-04-27 13:12:26 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-07-23 17:03:42 +0000},
    Journaltitle = {Environmental Health Perspectives},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {685 -- 696},
    Read = {0},
    Title = {Inorganic dust pneumonias: the metal-related parenchymal disorders},
    Volume = {108},
    }
```

**.sty file**

```
% Declare that this style file requires at least LaTeX version 2e.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

% Provide the name of your page, the date it was last updated, and a comment about what it's used for
\ProvidesPackage{assignments}[]

%=============================================================================
% PACKAGES AND SETTINGS

\RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, maxbibnames=99, firstinits=true, hyperref=true]{biblatex}

        % remove the "In:" preceeding the journal name
        \renewbibmacro{in:}{%
        \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

        % add space between bibliography entries by 50 %
        \setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
        \addbibresource{refs.bib}


%\RequirePackage{}
%\RequirePackage{}
%\RequirePackage{}
%\RequirePackage{}
\RequirePackage{caption}
            \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={color=PineGreen,bf},textfont=up,labelsep=period,format=hang,font=small}
            \captionsetup[table]{labelfont={color=PineGreen,bf},textfont=up, labelsep=period,format=hang,font=small}

\RequirePackage{minitoc}

\RequirePackage[american]{babel}
\RequirePackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts,amsmath,cancel,dsfont,textgreek}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{subfig}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{rotating}
\RequirePackage{pbox}
\RequirePackage{chemformula}
\RequirePackage{threeparttable} 
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks,
    linktocpage = true,
    citecolor=PineGreen,
    filecolor=PineGreen,
    linkcolor=PineGreen,
}
\RequirePackage{calc}

%=======================

% defining the chapter style
\renewcommand\colorchapnum{\color{PineGreen}}
\renewcommand\colorchaptitle{\color{PineGreen}}
\chapterstyle{pedersen} 


% defining the headers, footers, and pagestyle
\pagestyle{headings}

\makepagestyle{headings}
    \makeevenfoot{headings}{{\Large\color{PineGreen}\thepage}}{}{}
    \makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{{{\Large\color{PineGreen}\thepage}}}
    \makeevenhead{headings}{\footnotesize {\color{PineGreen}\rightmark}}{}{}
    \makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\footnotesize {\color{PineGreen}\leftmark}}
    \makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
    \makefootrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}

\makepagestyle{plain}
    \makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
    \makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}


\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty} %         pagestyle "plain" on first page of chapters
\aliaspagestyle{cleared}{empty} %       pagestyle "empty" on cleared pages (blank pages)



\OnehalfSpacing       % one-half spacing between adjacent lines of text, but not within captions and the like

\flushbottom          % stretch out pages to obtain equal height (default with twoside)
%\raggedbottom        % not stretch out pages

% ToC/ToF/ToT: page number next to entries
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}}  % empty pagestyle on toc page

\setsecnumdepth{subsection} % lowest structural level in toc

% setting color in toc
\setsecnumformat{\color{PineGreen}\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\setsecheadstyle{\color{PineGreen}\Large\bfseries\memRTLraggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\color{PineGreen}\Large\bfseries\memRTLraggedright}


\endinput
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I answered my own question this time. I tried to not "require biblatex package" in my package document, but instead used "usepcakge" in the actual thesis document. That seemed to solve the problem. Now everything works brilliantrly.